# How to selectively load device drivers in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, user-profiles

I sometimes hook up my laptop to a regular keyboard and mouse set. These require drivers that I don't want loaded when I'm using my laptop's own keyboard and touchpad. So...

- Can I tell Windows 7 to selectively load one or the other driver based on this condition, or switch between the two?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, although Windows will have appropriate drivers at the ready for external keyboards and mice, if they are not in use, the drivers won't be loaded.

In the greater scheme of things, the drivers required to operate these devices will be trivial both in terms of size and complexity, when compared with the 101 other drivers Windows 7 needs for all the other components. It's simply not an issue.

If you are noticing *any* difference when using external peripherals, you may have a separate problem, but that problem should be tackled explicitly.

Do you regard this as some sort of optimisation, or are you experiencing some sort of problem?

Comment: It's just for convenience. Now the `fn` key on my laptop's keyboard brings up the settings screen for my desktop's keyboard even when I'm not connected to it. I suppose there could be other conflicts with other special keys too.

Comment: I'd speak to the laptop manufacturer - they may have a way of configuring this behaviour - certainly worth a try.